# How to return a response from a post request with cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, rest, web-services, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a payment gateway with conekta but I cannot find a way to return the client code generated by conekta in the response of my post service.

```
app.post('/data/processPayment', async(req,res)=>{
try{
    var customId = ""
    const product_name =req.body.product_name
    const unit_price =req.body.unit_price
    const quantity =req.body.quantity
    const username =req.body.username
    const email =req.body.email
    const phone = req.body.phone
    const amount =req.body.amount
    const carrier =req.body.carrier
    const street1 =req.body.street1
    const postal_code =req.body.postal_code
    const description =req.body.description
    const reference =req.body.reference
    const type_payment =req.body.type_payment
    const card_token = req.body.card_token
    
   
    order = conekta.Order.create({
"line_items": [{
    "name": product_name,
    "unit_price": unit_price,
    "quantity": quantity
}],
"shipping_lines": [{
    "amount": amount,
    "carrier": carrier
}], //optional - shipping_lines are only required for physical goods
"currency": "MXN",
"customer_info": {
  'name': username,
  'email': email,
  'phone': phone
},
"shipping_contact":{
 "address": {
   "street1": street1,
   "postal_code": postal_code,
   "country": "MX"
 }
},  //optional - shipping_contact is only required for physical goods
"metadata": {  },
"charges":[{
"payment_method": {
  'type': 'card',
  'token_id': 'tok_test_visa_4242'
}  //payment_methods - use the customer's default - a card
   //to charge a card, different from the default,
   //you can indicate the card's source_id as shown in the Retry Card Section
}]
}, function(err, res) {
if(err){
  console.log(err);
  return;
}
//How can I return this value in my final response to my post request?
customId = res.toObject().id

})
//I try to return the data  but  customId it does not work
return res.status(200).json({message:"OK ", folio:" "+customId});
}
catch(error)
{
console.log(error)
return res.status(500).send(error);

}
})
```

I am trying to implement a payment gateway with conekta but I cannot find a way to return the client code generated by conekta in the response of my post service.

Answer (score 0):

The `create()` can be used with `await` instead of passing a callback. Try refactoring the code to:

```js
app.post('/data/processPayment', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    // declare all constants
    const newOrder = await conekta.Order.create({ ...params })
    // read customer ID/email from newOrder
    return res.status(200).json(newOrder)
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send(error)
  }
}
```